# Selenium - [error] Error: There was an unexpected Confirmation

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, confirm

I have a link that does a delete and has a confirm but I keep getting an error in SeleniumIDE

```
[error] There was an unexpected Confirmation
[Are you sure you want to delete all data and schedules for QA__run?]
```

I have tried adding chooseOkOnNextConfirmation before it but it didn't make any difference, I still get the error.

The HTML behind the delete link is:

```
<a class="deleteicon" title="Delete QA__run" rel="nofollow" 
data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" href="/districts/83">
  <img src="/assets/icons/delete-a77f3c....png" alt="Delete"></img>
</a>
```

and looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In selenium ide  after delete line script, Add this command

```
<tr>
    <td>storeConfirmation</td>
    <td>Are you sure you want to delete all data and schedules for QA__run?</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```